# Applying tinymce to dynamically created textarea works exactly once

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a page with three horizontal tabs. Clicking on a tab dynamically populates a div with a form. I am using BackboneJS to manage views' rendering (not sure if relevant). When I call render() on the view, after I populate the element's html, I make a call to apply tinyMCE to a text area:

```
$('#text_' + this.model.id, this.$el).tinymce({
                script_url : '/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
                theme : "modern",
                content_css: "/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                menubar: false,
                toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | " +
                    "bullist numlist outdent indent | link image |  forecolor backcolor emoticons",

                setup: function(editor) {
                    editor.on('change', function(e) {
                        var change = {};
                        change["content"] = e.level.content;
                        self.model.set(change);

                    });
                }
            });
```

This works perfectly fine on the first go. When view is removed, there is an event called that applies `.tinymce().remove();` to the field to properly remove editor before displaying the next view. The next view renders - it's the same view but different model. On this, and all subsequent calls, tinyMCE hides the textarea, and doesn't show the editor. I know my views work - commenting out .tinymce() call in render() makes everything work as intended. TinyMCE stumbles somewhere. Any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what `.tinymce().remove();` is doing but have you tried this:

```
tinymce.triggerSave();
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, tinymce.activeEditor.id);
```

and when you switch to the next view try re-attaching the editor via:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, selector);
```

If that doesn't work or doesn't apply to what you're doing. Have you considered having more than 1 tinyMCE editor? It sounds like you have a set number of tabs, so you could create a separate tinyMCE for each one and simply hide/show the editor on each as needed with:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceToggleEditor', false, selector);
```

This method is considered much faster than adding/removing the editor.